# Services monitoring each other

Tags: android

I'm trying have two services that monitor each other. If one is not running, I want to re-create that on the backup service.

I know I can use an AlarmManager to monitor them every x seconds, but how do I monitor them if the service is running?

I'm doing something like this, but my service is not showing up:

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
{
    if(ServiceObserverOne.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName()))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create two remote services,declare them in your manifest.xml

```
<service  
    android:name="ServiceOne"  
    android:process=":remote" >  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="***.ServiceOne" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</service>  

<service  
    android:name="ServiceTwo"  
    android:process=":remote" >  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="***.ServiceTwo" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</service>
```

then create a static method in MainActivity which can check the status of service(the service should be restarted if it returns false):

```
public static boolean isServiceWorked(Context context, String serviceName) {  
    ActivityManager myManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);  
    ArrayList<RunningServiceInfo> runningService = (ArrayList<RunningServiceInfo>) myManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);  
    for (int i = 0; i < runningService.size(); i++) {  
        if (runningService.get(i).service.getClassName().toString().equals(serviceName)) {  
            return true;  
        }  
    }  
    return false;  
}
```

the last step is try to monitor serviceOne when ServiceTwo starts work:

```
public class ServiceTwo extends Service {  

public final static String TAG = "com.example.ServiceTwo";  

@Override  
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");  

    thread.start();  
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;  
}  

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {  

    @Override  
    public void run() {  
        Timer timer = new Timer();  
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {  

            @Override  
            public void run() {  
                Log.e(TAG, "ServiceTwo Run: " + System.currentTimeMillis());  
                boolean b = MainActivity.isServiceWorked(ServiceTwo.this, "***.ServiceOne");  
                if(!b) {  
                    Intent service = new Intent(ServiceTwo.this, ServiceOne.class);  
                    startService(service);  
                }  
            }  
        };  
        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);  
    }  
});  
}
```

ServiceOne is the same as ServiceTwo...
hope it can help you..